# Upgrading Build for 6.0 projects, Cant set MSBuild to look for Reference assemblies in right place

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

so i have a build server on which i execute an Azure Pipline.
I have 100's of C# projects to compile, and it happens in a powershell task, where i go through all of the csproj paths, and execute MSBuild.exe for each of them.
up untill now i only had 4.6.1 projects, and now i also have 6.0 projects.
it seems like with 4.6.1, by default it was looking for referanced assemblies on the build's Binaris folder. which was very good.
now with 6.0 projects, MSbuild throws an Exception saying it cant find

Build_Source_Folderr\Referanced_Assembly_Dir\ obj\Debug\net6.0\ref\Referanced_Assembly.dll

chatGPT gave me some ideas, none of them worked-

- add Directory.Build.props and set ReferencePath or AssemblySearchPaths
- set MSBuild params like /p:BaseIntermediateOutputPath or /p:useCommonDir-true

i expect MSBuild to look for referanced assemblies in Build Binaries dir for 6.0 projects

Comment: Use project references or NuGet package references, *not* direct binary references.

Comment: What is the "Build Binaries dir"? Do you mean the directory identified by the pipeline predefined variable `Build.BinariesDirectory`? Neither .Net Framework nor .Net projects copy to the `Build.BinariesDirectory` unless the projects or the pipeline have been customized or configured to do so.

Comment: @JonathanDodds the point isnt where build artifacts are copied.
the point is where MSBuild looks for referanced assemblies. for FrameWork projects it looks in Build.BinariesDirectory , for Core projects in 
Build_Source_Folderr\Referanced_Assembly_Dir\ obj\Debug\net6.0\ref

Comment: 'Out of the box' MSBuild doesn't look in the `Build.BinariesDirectory` or the `Build.SourcesDirectory` for referenced assemblies. 'Referanced_Assembly_Dir' is a not a standard directory (even after correcting the spelling typo).

Comment: @JonathanDodds not out of the box, on MSBuild execution i set
 /p:outputpath=Build.BinariesDirectory. i guess that what also  makes MSBuild to look for referanced assemblies there. for 4.6.1, not 6.0. even tough execution line in code is exactly identicle for both frameworks..
as for Build_Source_Folderr\Referanced_Assembly_Dir it was to replace C:\agentt\work\1\s...\...\.., to emphesise the fact that its looking in build SOURCE dir.
as for spelling typo - how many languges do you speak? would rather have this converstaion in hebrew?

Comment: I meant no insult. I verified that 'Referanced_Assembly_Dir', 'Referenced_Assembly_Dir', 'ReferancedAssemblyDir', and 'ReferencedAssemblyDir' are not standard directories.

Comment: `OutputPath` is used by both legacy style and SDK style projects. Yes, the `OutputPath` of a project is one of the directories searched for referenced assemblies. As a bit of 'printf' debugging can you add a `Message` to the project that displays the value of `AssemblySearchPaths`?

Comment: @JonathanDodds sorry for over defenssive response and thnx for your attention :)
as far as i remember i only saw AssemblySearchPaths in Directory.Build.props, ill try and update here. thnx!!

Comment: How is the build order controlled? Conventionally a solution file (.sln) would list the projects, each project has its own `OutputPath`, and a project that depends on the assembly of another project would have a `ProjectReference`. The `ProjectReference` is used both to locate the assembly and to determine the build order. Build order can also be effected by build dependencies set in the solution file. If you are not using `ProjectReference`s and not using solution build dependencies, the projects could be building in the wrong order. The assembly is not found because it hasn't been built yet.